# 3D Pen in hand luggage

Tags: uk, air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

Flying from the UK, will I be allowed to take a 3D Pen with me in the cabin? It is basically a hand held 3D printer head. The tip gets very hot when working but it is powered via USB, so you can get an idea of how much power it consumes.

My concern is that it may be classed as a tool, as mostly everything in that category is banned. I've checked [what the UK has to say about tools in hand luggage](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/work-tools) but, as I more or less expected, there's nothing specific on a 3D pen.

Comment: It's basically a hand held 3d printer, right? Or that's what Google is trying to tell me.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, added as clarification, thanks.

Comment: Even the [US TSA pretty extensive list](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all) does not list them. The UK does not seem to have a system to make an inquiry like the TSA has (and you can't rely on the TSA's opinion, they are surprisingly a lot more relaxed than the UK on many items).

Comment: tools like screwdrivers, hammers, and wrenches are banned because you can hit people with them. If it is lightweight and expensive, there shouldn't be an issue. (Expensive/delicate things make sense to take in the cabin while hammers and wrenches do not.)

Comment: Personally I wouldn't take the chance and just put it in your suitcase. In my experience over the past couple of years the EU airport security officers are very randomly paranoid. Sometimes the same item will be let through without incident and other times it will be scanned a couple times and debated about before being let through.

Answer (score 5):

Not a proper answer since this is just anecdotical evidence, but I've just crossed security at Gatwick airport without any hiccups. They didn't even flag mi bag for manual inspection.